# How to Pass Object from android webview to c# to load html page

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, xamarin, xamarin.android

```
 WebView web_view = root.FindViewById<WebView>(Resource.Id.IVChartsViews); 

 String API = "http://Test.com/Sample/MobileApp?Userdetails=" + str + "&id=" + -9999;

 string obj1 = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(GlobalParams.ivs);
         HttpContent content = new StringContent(obj1.ToString());
         content.Headers.ContentType = new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");
         web_view.PostUrl(API, content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync().Result);
```

I am trying to load html page by passing object but it not working.

```
  public ActionResult MobileApp(string Userdetails, int? id, InfoViewSettings ivssettings){}
```

here ivsettings object taking default data. can you please tell me where am i doing mistake.

Comment: I can't find any relationship between your first snippet of code and your second one, what do you mean by "ivsettings object taking default data"? You want to use `WebView` to parse and show the Html string?

Comment: Yes want to use WebView to parse JsonObject and show the Html page.

Answer (score 0):

> Yes want to use WebView to parse JsonObject and show the Html page.

Just from your code, I still believe your JsonObject is parsed to a string and the content of this string should be a html content, you want your `WebView` to load this html content. If so, you can simply use `LoadData` method of `WebView` for example like this:

```cs
web_view.LoadData(htmlContent, "text/html; charset=utf-8", "UTF-8");
```

The `htmlContent` in the code above should be a string format of html content, for more information, you can refer [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html). And please make sure you've pass the right html content into this `LoadData` method.